# C# label gives an iteration

Tags: c#, iteration, goto

I just started learning C# couple of days ago. When came learn **goto** statement, I found the example like this.

```
        ineligible:
            Console.WriteLine("Not eligible for voting");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your age");
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            if (age < 18)
            {
                goto ineligible;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Voting request accepted");
            }
```

Then, I changed the code like this.

```
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        ineligible:
            Console.WriteLine("Not eligible for voting");

            if (age < 18)
            {
                goto ineligible;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Voting request accepted");
            }
```

and I got an infinite iteration **Not eligible for voting**. [Image of the iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygIb2.png)

Why an iteration happened instead of printing **Not eligible** only once ?

Reference: [javatpoint - C#(goto statement)](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-sharp-goto-statement)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: What do you think will happen after `Console.WriteLine("Not eligible for voting");` is done executing? What lines of code will execute next?

Comment: Just unlearn goto. You're better off without it. You have loops for this purpose.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - unless your question is about `.ReadLine` it should not show up in the sample code. With constants being inline you also should be able to eliminate unnecessary `if` branches... If you'd done you could have found answer yourslef...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to use this anywhere in your life. After reading this change the code, try once, learn it and then forget it.

**Why your first case worked?**

Because you have Console.Readline() so it will wait for your response.

```
ineligible:
        Console.WriteLine("Not eligible for voting");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your age");
        int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (age < 18)
        {
            goto ineligible;
        }
```

**Why second case leads to infinite loop?**

Because you have brought ineligible: just below to Console.ReadLine() statement.

```
int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        ineligible:
            Console.WriteLine("Not eligible for voting");
```

So the loop will be forever and it wont expect your input or disturbance.

Again learn it and forget it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described *why* you don't think they should use the `goto` statement, especially since they're just learning and [microsoft provides documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) that supports use cases for it (breaking out of nested loops, for example). Why do you state, *"You are not supposed to use this anywhere in your life"*?

Comment: Go to statement is very confusing one. It is just maintained for traditional purpose. If you need iterations there there is loop. If you need a function to be executed again and again then recursive function is there. If you want to come out of loop after certain condition then you have break statement. But goto will create a big confusion for developers who see your code. That's the reason.